# SharePoint Powershell Number and User columns

Tags: 2013, powershell, column, custom-field-types, field-definition

I need to create two list fields by powershell.
One that accept only Integer (type Number with no decimal) and the other User (multiple selection).

I can create Number field and Single User field with this code:

```
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::User
$myCustomList.Fields.Add("myUsers",$spFieldType,$false) 

$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Number
$myCustomList.Fields.Add("myNumber",$spFieldType,$false)
```

How can I add Integer and multiple users fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number field accepting only Integers (no decimal), do following:

```
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Number
$myField = $myCustomList.Fields.Add("myInteger",$spFieldType,$false)
$myIntegerField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldNumber]$myCustomList.Fields[$myField]
$myCustomList.Fields[$myIntegerField].DisplayFormat = SPNumberFormatTypes.NoDecimal
$myCustomList.Fields[$myIntegerField].Update()
```

User multi-selection

```
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::User
$myField = $myCustomList.Fields.Add("myMultiUsers",$spFieldType,$false)
$myMultiUsers = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUser]$myCustomList.Fields[$myField]
$myCustomList.Fields[$myMultiUsers].AllowMultipleValues = true
$myCustomList.Fields[$myMultiUsers].Update()
```

This should work !

Comment: The user is fine, but the Integer display only nodecimal in the view. (I want to avoid to insert new items with .00)

Comment: Even if the user adds .00 it will trim it and only show integer.. If you want client side validation on the control, you might need to inject JavaScript on the page..

Comment: I tried to add a validation formula "=MOD(['NameField'],1)<>0" but no luck :/

Comment: No this is client side validation and AFAIK you cannot have that until you restrict the textbox using some JavaScript..

Comment: $myCustomList.Fields[$myIntegerField].ValidationFormula is fine, now I need the MOD formula